# How to deal with clients errors (like Guzzle or Stripe PHP Client)

Tags: php, symfony, stripe-payments

I'm seeing myself troubling with the same problem again: how to deal with clients that make calls to external APIs?

The problem is this.

If I use, for example, Guzzle may happen it throws some [exceptions](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#exceptions) . The same happens, for example, again, with the Stripe PHP client (here the [documentation about errors](https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=php#errors)).

So, the problem is ever the same: for each call I make, I have to catch exceptions and act depending on their kind.

A typical example (taken from the Stripe's documentation):

```
try {
  // Use Stripe's library to make requests...
} catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
  // Since it's a decline, \Stripe\Error\Card will be caught
  $body = $e->getJsonBody();
  $err  = $body['error'];

  print('Status is:' . $e->getHttpStatus() . "\n");
  print('Type is:' . $err['type'] . "\n");
  print('Code is:' . $err['code'] . "\n");
  // param is '' in this case
  print('Param is:' . $err['param'] . "\n");
  print('Message is:' . $err['message'] . "\n");
} catch (\Stripe\Error\RateLimit $e) {
  // Too many requests made to the API too quickly
} catch (\Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest $e) {
  // Invalid parameters were supplied to Stripe's API
} catch (\Stripe\Error\Authentication $e) {
  // Authentication with Stripe's API failed
  // (maybe you changed API keys recently)
} catch (\Stripe\Error\ApiConnection $e) {
  // Network communication with Stripe failed
} catch (\Stripe\Error\Base $e) {
  // Display a very generic error to the user, and maybe send
  // yourself an email
} catch (Exception $e) {
  // Something else happened, completely unrelated to Stripe
}
```

So, if I make 3 calls to the API, I have to repeat this exception handling 3 times.

I can do better creating a method like `handleException(\Exception $e)` to use to manage the exceptions:

```
/**
 * Handles the Stripe's exceptions.
 *
 * @param \Exception $e
 */
private function handleException(\Exception $e)
{
    /* Since it's a decline, \Stripe\Error\Card will be caught
    $body = $e->getJsonBody();
    $err  = $body['error'];

    print('Status is:' . $e->getHttpStatus() . "\n");
    print('Type is:' . $err['type'] . "\n");
    print('Code is:' . $err['code'] . "\n");
    // param is '' in this case
    print('Param is:' . $err['param'] . "\n");
    print('Message is:' . $err['message'] . "\n");
    */

    // Authentication with Stripe's API failed
    if ($e instanceof \Stripe\Error\Authentication) {
        // Immediately re-raise this exception to make the developer aware of the problem
        throw $e;
    }
    elseif ($e instanceof \Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest) {
        // This should never happen: if we are in development mode, we raise the exception, else we simply log it
        die(dump($e));
    }
    elseif ($e instanceof \Stripe\Error\RateLimit) {
        // Too many requests made to the API too quickly
        die(dump('\Stripe\Error\Card error', $e));
    }
    elseif ($e instanceof \Stripe\Error\ApiConnection) {
        // Network communication with Stripe failed
        die(dump('\Stripe\Error\ApiConnection error', $e));
    }
    elseif ($e instanceof \Stripe\Error\Card) {
        die(dump('\Stripe\Error\Card error', $e));
    }
    elseif ($e instanceof \Stripe\Error\Base) {
        // Display a very generic error to the user, and maybe send
        // yourself an email
        die(dump('\Stripe\Error\Base error', $e));
    }
    elseif ($e instanceof \Exception) {
        // Something else happened, completely unrelated to Stripe
        die(dump('\Exception error', $e));
    }
```

But, again, the problem is: how to deal with errors?

Analizing each kind of exception:

1. `Authentication`: I raise it immeditely, as it is something that once fixed shoud never happen again: the developer has to simply check the access keys;
2. `InvalidRequest`: is problematic, see later;
3. `rateLimit`: I should implement some sort of exponential backoff [as suggested in the documentaion](https://stripe.com/docs/testing#rate-limits)
4. `Network communication`: I really don't know what to do neither how to simulate it
5. `Card`: I have not studied the problem now: I'd like to first solve other problems, especially with points 2 and 4.

So, see the `elseif (\Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest)`: what should have I to do if this exception is raised? In the comment I wrote that I can raise the exception if I'm in development mode, while if I'm not, I should log the error... But, is this the correct way to deal with the problem?

So, in definitive, and as I don't know well how to continue the discussion, how can I deal with the errors like this? The xaples are with the Stripe Api, but the same applies to Guzzle exceptions too, and tto many other libraries that use exceptions.

Is there some sort of guidance about how to deal with this kind of scenarios? Some best practices? Some examples from which I can get inspiration? Any suggestion or right direction is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you aware of Symfony's custom exception listener capability? http://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html At the very least this allows you to deal with the more esoteric exceptions in one spot.

Comment: Yes, ok, but the problem is that I don't know what to do after I catched the exception, not how to catch them. As you can read, in case of `RateLmit` exception I have to retry the call, but if I catch, for example, a `InvalidRequest` exception what should have I to do?

Comment: Since InvalidRequest should never happen in production then yes, log it and make sure somebody is notified right away that there is a problem.  But I understand the issues.  All I can suggest it looking at how some of the existing stripe bundles handle it.

Comment: The existing Stripe bundles 1) Are very old or 2) Don't handle the problem at all 3) are integrated in bigger bundles or some sort of mega-all-gateways-in-once, so they are unuseful or too much coplex to study :( For this reason I'm developing my own...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Middleware](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/handlers-and-middleware.html) FTW!!

Here's what you do.

When you create your object, you also create a middleware and then inject it.

```
$handler = new CurlHandler();
$stack   = HandlerStack::create($handler);
$stack->push(ErrorHandlerMiddleware::create(), 'http_error');
```

Then your ErrorHandlerMiddleware could look like this:

```
class ErrorHandlerMiddleware {
    public static function create() {
        return function (callable $handler) {
            return function ($request, array $options) use ($handler {

            return $handler($request, $options)->then(
                function (ResponseInterface $response) use ($request, $handler) {
                    $code = $response->getStatusCode();
                    if ($code < 400) {
                        return $response;
                    }
                    $response_body = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
                    switch ($code) {
                        case 400:
                            // do what you need
                        case 404:
                            // do what you need
                        case 500:
                            // do what you need
                    }
                },
                function (RequestException $e) use ($request, $handler) {
                    throw new Exceptions\ConnectException('Service Unavailable - Connection Errors '. $e->getMessage(), $request);
                }
            );
        };
    };
}
```

}

Now you don't have to repeat yourself.

PS: when I say "do what you need" I mean throw your custom exceptions or whatever you need to do